# First learning ASP.NET MVC 3.0 is panic, we want to help

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Currently our company is using a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 RC2 development environment. The first contacts do not know where to start learning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a short ASP.NET MVC 2 tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490371/looking-for-a-short-asp-net-mvc-2-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos

Best place to start. :)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Coaches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/msdn.coach) is a good start I think. There are good [lessons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/dd627541).